# Connecting to a cassandra cluster after a new node has been added

Tags: cassandra

How do we connect to a cassandra cluster after a new node has been added? Do we need to add the new IP address to the connection string? Is there a way to auto discover the new nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we need to add the new IP address to the connection string?

No, you don't need to worry about that.

All your driver code needs is the IPs of a few nodes running to use as an entry point into the cluster.  Once it has that, it reads the token range assignment information.  From that, it can tell when new nodes are added and incorporates those into its future query plans.